# Why is TypeScript unable to infer the type properly?

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

I have two examples where TypeScript type inference is not working as I expect it, maybe these two are related, maybe it's a TS bug, maybe I am only too dumb to understand it.

### Example #1

```
interface AType {
  type: 'A'
  message: string
}

interface BCType {
  type: 'B' | 'C'
}

type Test = AType | BCType

function doSomething(test: Test) {
  if (test.type !== 'B' && test.type !== 'C') {
    test.message
  }
}
```

The `test.message` gets the error

```
Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Test'.
  Property 'message' does not exist on type 'BCType'.ts(2339)
```

Why isn't `test` of AType now, so it has a `message` property? If I remove the `'C'` from the type, it works. If I check for `=== 'A'`, is also works.

### Example #2

```
interface AType {
  type: {
    id: 'A'
  }
  message: string
}

interface BType {
  type: {
    id: 'B'
  }
}

type Test = AType | BType

function doSomething(test: Test) {
  if (test.type.id === 'A') {
    test.message
  }
}
```

Same here:

```
Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Test'.
  Property 'message' does not exist on type 'BType'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: Discriminants must be literal types. This works https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBUCeAHFBvAKGWTBwgC5kByVKo5AWwgGdm4BzC5ZsKUdggF8CBUJFiIUAISy5khYqVyUqUqsiEix0eEmQBhWfnpKuVfes2nk6FmGQBeNEeQAfZDLJuDRkTACuIAhgwAD2IMgAJqEAyqFMYAAW-AAUkDyUtjwAlPL0wDDIaXYAdNYAhA5OquoAZLUkpRVV1Ba5CsSNPCVMrBwQ9MKCQA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type guards generally work on the `field` of variable they are applied to, so if you narrow `test.type`, the narrowing generally applies to just `type` not to `test`. The one exception to this is if the type of `test` is a discriminated union and `test` is a the discriminant field.

For the property to be a discriminant property, it [must](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30506#issuecomment-474802840) fulfill some requirements:

1. The property is a literal type as outlined here [Discriminated union types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9163)
2. The a property of a union type to be a discriminant property if it has a union type containing at least one unit type and no instantiable types as outlined here [Allow non-unit types in union discriminants](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27695)

As for the second example, there just isn't support for nested discriminated unions. There is a [proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758) to support this but it has been open for 3 years, without much movement.

You can adjust your model to conform to discriminated union rules, or, as a work around, you can use custom type guards:

```
interface AType {
  type: 'A'
  message: string
}

interface BCType {
  type: 'B' | 'C'
}

type Test = AType | BCType

function doSomething(test: Test) {
  if (!isBC(test)) {
    test.message
  }
}

function isBC(o: any): o is BCType {
  return o?.type != "B" && o?.type != "C"
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBUCeAHFBvAWAChlkwcIAuZAclRuNIFsIBnVuAcyuVbClCdiAX2LFQkWIhQAhAMJZcyQiTIVqNGTWQAfWnIZFRRYuSXo2YZAF40ilHvn2xRGAFcQCMMAD2IZAAmPgDKPixgABaCABSQfNQWfACUyozIwDDI0QCEwKzysZZJKSqkpHFgAHQs7FwQacbGxO6e3n7p+XLRPtRwIJhJ1D4dyE4UqapQEGBuUP4+APyVZijZtgBEMuvIAGQ7yIvL42vI63LrIkA)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that the topic is that specific, but good to know, and your explanation is good to understand.